# Doctrine CreateQueryBuilder returns repeated result

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

In Symfony3 I'm running

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entity --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Post
```

It creates 2 files: `Post` (in entity folder) and `PostRepository` (in repository folder extending `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`)

Everything is fine until I try to run the following repository-custom-function in my controller

```
$rir = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBlogBundle:Post");
$replacementInstruction = $rir->getOneBy(
    array("id" => 6)
);
```

My custom repository function is as follow

```
public function getOneBy($option)
{
    $alias = "p";
    $fields = $this->prepareRequestSelectFields("p");

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Post');

    $qb->select($fields)
        ->from('AcmeBlogBundle:Post', $alias)
        ->where($alias . '.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', 6)
    ;

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

private function prepareRequestSelectFields($alias)
{
    return  $alias. ".id";
}
```

In my database there are 10 posts with id from 1 to 10, so I expect it to return 1 result, however it return correct Post (id 6) 10 times

Why is that?

p.s. if I move the query builder to a custom service wrapper e.g. PostManager it works just fine (returning 1)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer my question but apparently `createQueryBuilder()` in `EntityRepository` and in `EntityManager` are different, thanks to https://maltronic.io/2014/12/22/doctrine-createquerybuilder-entitymanager-vs-entityrepository/

So in my EntityRepository it should be

```
...

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p'); // this should be the alias

$qb->select($fields)
    // ->from('AcmeBlogBundle:Post', $alias) // remove this
    ->where($alias . '.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', 6)
;
...
```

Personally I dislike how 2 different functions has the same name, but I guess it's fine because one is from Doctrine and one is from Symfony. They are decoupled

**edit** Actually I might be wrong, they are both from Doctrine ... sigh

Still tho, it doesn't answer why in my original code, it returns multiple time

Answer (score 0):

What about getSingleResult() rather than getResult() ? And you should maybe use the doctrine method [findOneBy()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database)

Comment: Unfortunately in my original code, `getSingleResult()` throws `\Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException` and that was caused by createQueryBuilder in `EntityRepository` needs different parameters. In other words, it's already broken before `getSingleResult()` or `getResult()`

Comment: setMaxResults(1) then (not realy resolving the problem). But I think you are out of line here, you should get the complete entity with findOneBy() and then use the fileds/properties you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper methods provided by the repositories, allowing you to fetch one or multiples entities from repositories with dynamic method names, in your case you want to fetch **one** post by **id**:

```
//fetch one    
$replacementInstruction = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBlogBundle:Post")->findOneById(6);
```

For information, fetching all entities is done with ->findBy*Property*

Comment: Thanks, while nothing wrong with your answer, my intention is to use `createQueryBuilder()` instead. One of the reason is because I only need a few attribute from the entity not all which I can filter via `->select()` for that custom function